# How long does it take for Cloudfront to use new SSL Cert?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront

I have cloudfront using my new SSL cert.  How long will it take for the browser to recognize this new cert?  I've been waiting 10~ minutes and opened it up incognito mode and the old cert still pops up.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but mostly all changes to settings of AWS take effect immediately. However, with CloudFront, you might need to "push" your changes to the edge locations if you don't want to wait for the TTL to expire. Important note: pushing your changes to the edge locations is not free!

Comment: Damn you Bezos!!!

Comment: How exactly did you change to the new certificate?

Comment: Using the AWS CLI - aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name mydomain.com --certificate-body file://mydomain.crt --private-key file://mydomain.pem --certificate-chain file://mydomain.ca-bundle

Comment: CloudFront certificates in IAM have to have a `--path`.  Also, using IAM for this is (sort of) deprecated.  You can now import your cert into Amazon Certificate Manager, which supports both the CLI and the console.